# Displaying users with a php, sql count?

Tags: php, sql, count

I have a database with users input and was wanting to output a user table (id, username) as a count on a page. The following piece of code is what I've been trying to work with but I've been having no luck and it keeps getting more and more complex - the SQL works perfectly so I'm not sure what's wrong.

```
mysqli_select_db($db);
$result = $_POST ['$result'] ;
$result = mysqli_query("SELECT COUNT( * ) 
FROM users");
$row = mysqli_real_escape_string($result,$db);
$total = $row[0];
echo "Total rows: " . $total;
```

I'm still learning how to properly link SQL in with PHP. The warnings tell me to add an extra parameter however when I do so it still complains.

I originally wanted a simple COUNT but will change the count to a table array if need be. I understand this maybe a little basic and I may have been going about it the wrong way, but I've hit a wall with it and any help on fixing the COUNT would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Replace the call to mysqli_real_escape_string to mysqli_fetch_array and your code will works.

mysqli_real_escape_string is only useful for string escaping when you INSERT or UPDATE data to MySQL.

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_array ($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM users";
$result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);

// Numeric array
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_NUM);
$number = count($rows);
```

Hope this works.